# Cron job executing shell script sending empty email

Tags: bash, cron, oraclelinux

I wrote a shell script to automatically check the status of Oracle Data Guard and send it via mail.

If I execute the script manually it works like it should.

If I execute the script via a cronjob it just sends empty emails.
This behaviour started only after we updated our servers from oracle linux 7 to oracle linux 8.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#. ~/envBIPROD.sh
source /home/oracle/.bash_profile
source /home/oracle/envBIPROD.sh

dgmgrl -silent  user/pass >biprod.txt << EOF
show configuration;
show database p1biprod;
show database s1biprod;
EOF

cat biprod.txt | mail -r $(whoami).$(hostname -s)@hostname.tld -s "DATA GUARD Status biprod" RECEPIENT@hostname.tld
```

This is the "envBIPROD.sh" script which sets the oracle home:

```
export ORACLE_SID=BIPROD1
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
. oraenv
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/OPatch:$PATH
```

Also the file "biprod.txt" is just empty when the script is run by cron.

Comment: most cron problems are you assuming things about the permissions or the environment of the cron user. e.g. the PATH isn't what you think it is, some environment variable isn't what you think it is, or the exact user and group permissions of cron isn't what you think it is. For example, you seem to be assuming ORACLE_HOME is set when cron runs it. That's doubtful. A start would be running ```env``` in the script so you can see what your environment is.

Comment: I know that ORACLE_HOME is not set, thats why I execute `envBIPROD.sh` which invokes the oraenv utility to set the ORACLE_HOME.

Comment: keep looking, there is something different about the environment or permissions. Run ```id``` to see what username and groups you are in shell and in cron. Start a new bash with nothing  ```env - bash```, then source those scripts, and see if it still runs.

Comment: Standard cron job troubleshooting: capture errors & output from the job by adding something like `>>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` to the command in crontab (and if you have anything like `2>/dev/null`, remove it -- that's hiding errors, which is the opposite of what you want). Then check the log after it runs and see if you see anything informative.

Comment: Thats my Cron Call: `9 0 * * * /cloudfs/dba/scripts/data_guard_status_mail_BIPROD.sh 2>&1 >> /cloudfs/dba/scripts/data_guard_status_mail_BIPROD.log` . In the data_guard_status_mail_BIPROD.log is only this line over and over again: `Null message body; hope that's ok`. I also tried to do what xpusostomos suggested, I started a new bash and then run the script. worked as intended when run manually

Comment: You need to put the `2>&1` *after* the `>> /cloudfs/dba/scripts/data_guard_status_mail_BIPROD.log` or it won't work.

Comment: And as you're using `>>` be sure that you are looking at the end of the file, to see the results from the most recent run (how do I know that? (-;? Nevermind!) ... Good pointers above. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your script is probably running in a directory where it doesn't have permission to create or write to a file and so `>biprod.txt` is failing to create the file or to overwrite an existing file.

If `biprod.txt` is intended to only exist while your script is running then do this instead:

```
biprod=$(mktemp) || exit 1
trap 'rm -f "$biprod"; exit' EXIT

dgmgrl -silent  user/pass > "$biprod" 
...

cat "$biprod" | ...
```

though you almost certainly could be using `< "$biprod" mail ...` instead of `cat "$biprod" | mail ...`). It wouldn't hurt for you to add some `printf`s to report failures either.

Comment: It is commented out because I wanted to see if it works with the `source` command, which basically should do the same. I dont think it has no permissions, because the cronjob creates a empty file , which it would not be doing if there was no permissions to this folder

Comment: You didn't mention that `~` expands to `/home/oracle`, I thought they were 2 different directories, I'll remove that part of my answer. Are you sure the crontab creates an empty file and it's not just that an empty file of that name exists which crontab doesn't have permission to write to or that crontab is trying to create one in a different directory? Have you checked the timestamp on biprod.txt to make sure that changes when the cron job runs? Have you tried replacing `dgmgrl ...>biprod.txt << EOF ... EOF` with `echo 'hello world' > biprod.txt` to see if THAT succeeds?